# Neo4j on Amazon EC2 - Not accessible from remote machines

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j, rhel

I am currently attempting to get neo4j installed properly on an EC2 instance with RHEL.  Currently I can not hit the server on port 7474 from a browser to see the neo4j webadmin or browser.  As of right now I can successfully access localhost:7474 which leads me to believe it is some level of access issue with remote connections.

What I have done so far:

1. Installed Oracle Java 1.7 on the EC2 instance
2. Installed neo4j-community-2.0.1
3. Added org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0 to the neo4j-server.properties
4. Added a custom TCP rule in EC2 UI for port 7474 allowing 0.0.0.0/0
5. Added 7474 to iptables
6. Restarted the instance
7. run neo4j start

Looking at netstat I see the process listening on port 7474, so I am unsure what else would be preventing external traffic from hitting the public EC2 DNS for the server on port 7474.

console.log

```
2014-02-24 20:25:24.572+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2014-02-24 20:25:27.226+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
2014-02-24 20:25:28.924+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 10 threads available
2014-02-24 20:25:29.387+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
2014-02-24 20:25:30.077+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted discovery module at [/]
2014-02-24 20:25:30.088+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at [/db/data/]
2014-02-24 20:25:30.097+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted management API at [/db/manage/]
2014-02-24 20:25:30.099+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted webadmin at [/webadmin]
2014-02-24 20:25:30.100+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted Neo4j Browser at [/browser]
2014-02-24 20:25:30.202+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
2014-02-24 20:25:30.326+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
15:25:30.328 [main] WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@164cc9b7{/,null,null} contextPath ends with /
15:25:30.328 [main] WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Empty contextPath
15:25:30.331 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.0.5.v20130815
15:25:30.387 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@5e9c3ce7{/,null,AVAILABLE}
15:25:30.780 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
15:25:30.802 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@488a358e{/webadmin,jar:file:/opt/neo4j-community-2.0.1/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.1-static-web.jar!/webadmin-html,AVAILABLE}
15:25:31.964 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@750e589{/db/manage,null,AVAILABLE}
15:25:32.759 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1480606f{/db/data,null,AVAILABLE}
15:25:32.787 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /browser, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
15:25:32.789 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3f773163{/browser,jar:file:/opt/neo4j-community-2.0.1/system/lib/neo4j-browser-2.0.1.jar!/browser,AVAILABLE}
15:25:33.047 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@164cc9b7{/,null,AVAILABLE}
15:25:33.078 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@14cfe45e{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7474}
15:25:34.498 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@44590060{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7473}
2014-02-24 20:25:34.500+0000 INFO  [API] Remote interface ready and available at [http://0.0.0.0:7474/]
```

neo4j.0.0.log:

```
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:24 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:27 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Successfully started database
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:28 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 10 threads available
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:29 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:30 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted discovery module at [/]
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:30 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted REST API at [/db/data/]
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:30 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted management API at [/db/manage/]
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:30 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted webadmin at [/webadmin]
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:30 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted Neo4j Browser at [/browser]
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:30 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:30 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:31 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:31 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:32 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Feb 24, 2014 3:25:34 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Remote interface ready and available at [http://0.0.0.0:7474/]
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.. I can connect from on the machine but not externally..

Answer (score 0):

Is your EC2 instance part of a security group within a VPC?
As a troubleshooting technique - you can try to put nginx as a proxy that does 80<->7474, and see if that gives you a way to at least access it while you work through the issues...

Answer (score -2):

I had the exact same problem, which turned out to result from how security groups are administered in EC2. Basically I had to go to "Network Interfaces", select "Actions", then "Change Security Groups", and then add my newly created security group.